# -Wordpress plugin- correctly way to include js files without wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've been usually to include JavaScript files in my plugins in the following way:

```
function A_pubblish_scriptFEnd(){
    $A_scriptFE=plugins_url( 'Js/CPFront.js', __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'CP-js-FE', $A_scriptFE, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'A_pubblish_scriptFEnd' );
```

It worked for every single plugin but now I'm having a problem if I upload more than one plugin WordPress gives me an error, cause I can't repeat wp_enqueue_scripts more than one time.

How can I include in a correct way multiple js files for multiple plugin?
What is the correct way to include files in the main php file?

Comment: The problem likely isn't you using `wp_enqueue_scripts` several times but using the same function name on all of your plugins without a namespace. Can't tell for sure though unless you share some more code and/or the error message(s) you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to enqueue scripts.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme', 'style.css', false );
}
 
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```

Having multiple actions on the wp_enqueue_scripts hook is perfectly fine.
( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/ )